# Dates, timezone and POSIXct

Tags: r, time, timezone, posixct

I just fread a large datafile, and the "DATE" column is stored as character like O5JAN2004, 06JAN2004.The time in this datafile is matched to NewYork time, and I live in Los Angeles.

Then I use as.Date to convert character to date.

```
t <- as.Date(key$DATE[1], format = "%d%b%Y")
[1] "2004-01-05"
```

But when I use as.POSIXct(t), it returns me:

```
 > as.POSIXct(t)
[1] "2004-01-04 16:00:00 PST"
 > as.POSIXlt(t)
[1] "2004-01-05 UTC"
```

I tried several methods mentioned on website, but the result didn't change:

```
t <- as.Date(key$DATE[1], format = "%d%b%Y", 'PST')
t <- as.Date(key$DATE[1], format = "%d%b%Y", 'EST')
t <- as.Date(key$DATE[1], format = "%d%b%Y", tz="America/New_York")
t <- as.Date(keyi$DATE[1], format = "%d%b%Y", tz="America/Los_Angeles")
as.POSIXct(t, tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
as.POSIXct(t, tz = "America/New_York")
```

I want to know: what could I do so when I use as.POSIXct(t), it would return me "2004-01-05 PST" or any other timezone.

I am thinking because the Date is originally stored as character, so it wouldn't remember its original timezone, right?

I do get

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(t))
> "2004-01-05"
```

But why would as.POSIXct(t) return the previous result? Because I also have other data files and I would get "2004-01-05 PST" using as.POSIXct(t).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your `as.POSIXlt(t)`  shows that `as.Date` is using GMT by default. But `as.POSIXct` uses local time by default, so there is an unwanted conversion. But you can fix this.

`strptime` has a `tz` argument to specify the base time zone.   This worked for me:

```
t = strptime(key$DATE[1], format = "%d%b%Y", tz= "America/Los_Angeles")
as.POSIXct(t)
[1] "2004-01-05 PST"
```

Warning: What does and does not work as a value for tz seems to be rather odd.

Comment: Thank you! I have have a try!